# zkSnark: Restricting a Polynomial

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, number-theory

I am reading this explanation of zkSnark written by Maksym Petkus -  http://www.petkus.info/papers/WhyAndHowZkSnarkWorks.pdf

I have understood everything in the first 15 pages.

In **3.4 Restricting a Polynomial** (Page 16)

> We do already restrict a prover in the selection of encrypted powers of s, but such restriction is not enforced, e.g., one could use
> any possible means to find some arbitrary values $z_p$ and $z_h$ which satisfy equation $z_p = (z_h)^{t(s)}$ and provide them to the verifier instead of $g^p$ and $g^h$. For example, for some random r $z_h = g^r$ and $z_p = (g^{t(s)})^{r}$, where $g^{t(s)}$ can be computed from the provided encrypted powers of $s$. That is why verifier needs the proof that only supplied encryptions of powers of $s$ were used to calculate
> $g^p$ and $g^h$ and nothing else.

I am unable to understand how a prover can find some arbitrary values of $z_p$ and $z_h$ which satisfy $z_p = (z_h)^{t(s)}$? For example, for some random r $z_h = g^r$ and $z_p = (g^{t(s)})^{r}$

The prover doesn't know $s$ & nor does he know $g$, so how will he do this?

In short, I am unable to figure out what is the attack (to protect against) for which "restricting a polynomial" is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per page 15 of the paper, the prover is provided with $E(s^0)=E(1)=g$ (I'll refer to this as $E_0$). Likewise they are provided with
$$E_1:=E(s), E_1:=E(s^2),\cdots, E_d:=E(s^d).$$
Let $t(s)=\sum_{0\le i\le d}c_is^i$ (with the $c_i$ known to the prover) then $g^{t(s)}=E(t(s))=\prod_{0\le i\le d}E_i^{c_i}$.

Thus prover knows both $g$ and $g^{t(s)}$ and as in the paper they may choose a random $r$ to construct $z_h$ and $z_p$ by raising these value to the power $r$.

The point of the attack is that the above calculations do not require knowledge of $p(x)$ which is what prover is supposed to be proving knowledge of. A verifier foolish enough to believe that the random value $z_h$ does equal $g^{h(s)}$ and that $z_p$ does equal $g^{p(s)}$ will have nothing to contradict their belief.

Comment: I know I already accepted the answer. However, I tried an example & it didn't work.

Comment: E(c) = g^c mod 23. Verifier samples at s = 14 & provides $E(s^0) = 5$, $E(s^1) = 13$, $E(s^2) = 12$, $E(s^3) = 3$

The 2 known roots are 3 & 4 i.e. $t(s) = (x-3)(x-4)$. 

Prover chooses a random r = 6. t(6) = 3 * 2 = 6. Prover calculates $z_h = 5^6 \pmod {23} = 8$ & $z_p = (5^6)^6 \pmod {23} = 13$ 
Sends $z_p$ and $z_h$ to verifier

Verifier calculates t(14) = 11 * 10 = 110. Verifier calculates $E(h)^t = 8^{110} \pmod {23} = 1$. So $E(p) \ne E(h)^t$



What am I doing wrong? Have I misunderstood your answer?

Comment: The prover does not compute $t(r)$ and then $g^{t(r)}$. Instead, they compute  $g^{t(s)}=g^{s^2−7s+12}=12×13^{−7}×5^{12}$ and raise this to the power $r$. Firing up sagemath, we see that $g^{t(s)}\equiv 1\pmod{23}$, so prover sets $z_p=1^r\equiv 1\pmod{23}$ and $z_h=8$. They then compute $z_h^{110}=8^{110}\equiv 1\pmod{23}$ which is the same value.

Comment: Ok, that checks out!!

Comment: I found another problem with the protocol described in 3.3 Let the actual true 3rd root be 0 i.e. the true polynomial is (x)(x-3)(x-4). Even if the prover didn't know the true polynomial & the true root & he assumed that the 3rd root was instead 2 instead of 0 & that the polynomial was (x-2)(x-3)(x-4) & do all the steps - the steps still check out and the verifier wouldn't know that prover didn't know the right polynomial. I was wondering if this is a separate fault with the protocol explained in 3.3 or is it a variation of the same mentioned in 3.4. I think it's a diff fault

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the sample value chosen, $s=14$ is a root of $t(x)$ modulo 22 which is the order of the group mod 23. This leads to $z_p=1$ which causes degeneracy as you have found. The verifier should check before sending that $t(s)\not\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ for a large prime $q$ dividing $p-1$. This is very likely to be the case if we use a large, strong prime.

Comment: Are you saying both the problems (one described in 3.4 & the one I pointed out in my last comment) are because $s=14$ is a root of $t(x) \pmod {22}$ or is only one of them because of this?

Comment: So, I tried both the issues with s = 16 which is not a root . And both the issues still remain. So having s as a root of t(s) mod (p-1) does cause E(p) to always be 1, but otherwise how does it cause any problems with the protocol?

Comment: I don't have an issue with $s=16$. For the polynomial $t(x)=x(x-3)(x-4)$, $t(s)=2496$. For the polynomial $(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)=x^3-9x^2+26x-24$ the prover would compute $E(s^3)E(s^2)^{-9}E(s)^{26}E(1)^{-24}=8$. Picking random $r=6$ prover sends $z_h=8$ and $z_p=13$. Verifier then has $z_h^{2496}=3$ which is not the same as $z_p$.

Comment: p(x) = x(x-3)(x-4), t(x) = (x-3)(x-4) - so t(16) = 156 & not 2496. $13^{156} \pmod {23} \equiv 8$ - hence matches